# Elasticsearch sort terms/top_hits

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use `terms/top_hits` aggregations to get best results for each category and then sort them. Currently, my query looks like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_id",
        "size": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "rating": "desc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works well and documents within each `category_id` are sorted.

Now, I need to sort those selected hits by other criteria, i.e.

```
"sort": [
  {
    "price": "asc"
  }
]
```

At the end I need a hit within each category with the best rating and then I want to sort those best hits by price.

But I don't know where to put this sorting. On the top level it doesn't sort buckets. Inside `by_category` (`terms` aggregation) it doesn't work. Inside `top_hits` I need another sorting.

I saw the solution with `_score`, but I need sorting by multiple fields.

How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: `sort` block takes an array and you can add `{ "price" : "asc" }` after existing sorting criteria.

Comment: Then hits will be sorted by rating and price inside each bucket. But I want to sort *buckets*. I'll update my question to avoid confusion.